# jquery - conflcting/multiple $(this)My in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Code looks like

```
  $(".div-text").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".items").find("img.mainImage").each(function() {
       // following this should correspond to mainImage elements and not outside "this"
       alert($(this).data("src")) ----------> **this "this" does not work**
    })
  });
```

How can I have two this corresponding to different elements or

what is the alternative for code above???

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside the `each` loop refers to the current `mainImage` which is being looped through not the clicked `div-text` element.

A possible solution is to use a closure variable as shown below

```
$(".div-text").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = this;
    $(this).parents(".items").find("img.mainImage").each(function () {
        // following this should correspond to mainImage elements and not outside "this"
        alert($(self).data("src"))
    })
});
```

Comment: You are right...It was a bug in my code...thanks a lot for your help.